# Parse readonly string with escaping quotes to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

The title of my question can be somewhat confusing, so I'll try to explain my situation:

From an external source (in this case a Web Socket connection), I receive a JSON string that needs to be parsed to an object in JavaScript.
I do **not** have the possibility to modify the fashion how the string is built up in the external source. I know that there are several options to parse, like using jQuery, `eval()` (not always recommended), etc ...
In this case, I just use `JSON.parse()` because it seems to work just fine.

Today I ran into a problem with double quotes being escaped in the string. Take the following example:

> var readonly = '{"nam":"jso\"n"}';

Suppose that `readonly` is the string that is received from the external source (as the name suggests, I can't modify how the string is formatted at this level). This is actually valid JSON, to there's really no reason for me to complain to the developers of the external source that they should modify theirs.
Now I would like to parse this string to an object. As already mentioned, I use `JSON.parse()` for this:

> var my_object = JSON.parse(readonly);

This unfortunately fails, and the browser's console throws an error message.

After research, I found that I need to add another backslash to escape the double quotes in order for this to work. So I need to find a way to change the `readonly` string into this:

> '{"nam":"jso\\"n"}'

My question now is: How can I add these extra backslashes to strings of which I don't know their content up front?

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments, here's some extra info:
I actually receive a string that contains more than just the json. A fixed number of characters are in front an behind of the json. This could be an example:

> 'xxxx{"nam":"jso\"n"}xxxxxx'

I use `substring` to extract the actual json from this string.

Comment: If `{"nam":"jso\"n"}` really were received over the socket, the `JSON.parse` call would not fail. If you're *testing*, and creating that string as in the code, the problem is that you need to double the backslash: `{"nam":"jso\\"n"}`

Comment: Do you receive an actual JSON string or some JavaScript code that contains a variable declaration?

Comment: @Pointy I added more information about my use case. You will see that I don't have the option to alter this.

Comment: @BramW. you don't have to alter anything. The problem you think you have doesn't really exist. When the JSON is received over the socket, it will work. When you're testing your code with hard-coded JSON in JavaScript string constants, *then* you need the double backslash.

Comment: And that's true even if there are extra characters that you have to remove.

Comment: @Pointy Can you take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4w8cxpyo/ How would I start using the result as an object, so I can ask in this case for the nam property?

Comment: OK, one more time: in your fiddle, your code is **not** receiving the JSON over a web socket.  You're trying to put the JSON inside a JavaScript string constant, and *that* is why you need the two backslash characters instead of just one. If the JSON were really coming from a web socket API, then it would already be correct and `JSON.parse()` would not fail.

Answer (score 2):

The string is incorrect - it needs to be double escaped.

```
var readonly = '{"nam":"jso\\"n"}';
                           ^^
```

Remember that you're defining this string as a javascsript string, which means it's parsed/evaluated by Javascript **FIRST*. That means the characters literally stored in the var will simply be `{"nam":"json"n"}` - the JS parser will have removed the backslash. And now it's corrupted/invalid json.

By doubling up the backslashes, you ensure that ONE of the backslashes will survive and be present to make it valid JSON, which can then be parsed.

Comment: Right. But when the string is recieved over the socket, it will be assembled into a JavaScript string but *not* via the JavaScript parser. The source service need not double the backslash. (I know you know that, just adding that for those following along at home.)

Comment: I added more information about my use case. You will see that I don't have the option to alter this.